# JavaFX LineChart delta must be positive exception

Tags: java, javafx, linechart

For some reason even though my data list size is 0,

```
JavaFX Application Thread gives IllegalArgumentException: delta must be positive
```

`at org.gillius.jfxutils.chart.StableTicksAxis.calculateTickSpacing line:195` etc.

If I choose different element lists to show, they work really good even though if my data list size is 0 but for some reason this list doesnt work. Do you have any ideas why can this happen?

Btw, by different list I mean my Y-Axis elements for LineChart. Can this be from corrupt data?

Comment: Add some of your code please... especially everything related to line 195. Do you manually pass the *delta* argument?

Comment: Well, line 195 is actually a library not my own code so you can find it on internet. There's no error on my code. And delta argument is something that framework uses its own, I dont send it, just bind it

Comment: Then please add two examples: One that works and another one that doesn't... You are talking about different lists for y-axis values, that is what I mean.